# Where can I find API documentation for tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking for a **complete** online reference for Python's `tkinter` module.
 I've tried to find one by myself, but for some reason I can't.

To clarify, I am **not** looking for a tutorial. Instead, I would like to have a reference for all the available classes and attributes.

For example, if I write this code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("My title")
```

I wonder: what optional arguments does the `Tk` class accept for instantiation? What are properties and methods for a `Tk` object? What arguments does `title` accept? And so on...

"Look at the source" is not an answer to this question, obviously.

Answer (score 8):

For a definitive guide to all of the options supported by each widget you should consult the [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm). It's a fairly trivial mental exercise to translate the tcl into python. The only real problems are when the tcl options conflict with python reserved words (such as the `-in` option for pack and grid)

Comment: They also have a python tutorial on the website, and after looking at it, I am beginning to wonder why I should use Tkinter widgets and not Tk since tk just look great on windows!

Answer (score 6):

There were 2 books that were very useful to me:

- Mark Roseman's [*Modern Tkinter for Busy Python Programmers*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0071QDNLO)
- John Grayson's [*Python and Tkinter Programming*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1884777813).

They are very complete. They might be hard to find online.

Comment: [Mark Roseman's book](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafykbzaceboqjloczrd2d2asgd54kos4gulfalqp4zl4tkpcevdq4xvg4x4l6?filename=Mark%20Roseman%20-%20Modern%20Tkinter%20for%20Busy%20Python%20Developers_%20Quickly%20learn%20to%20create%20great%20looking%20user%20interfaces%20for%20Windows%2C%20Mac%20and%20Linux%20using%20Python%27s%20standard%20GUI%20toolkit%20%282012%29.pdf)

Comment: [John Grayson's book](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafykbzaceaqfbusocy2ll4on7fznmism2zkkpfrvf2ilp3oxscgjiz5butcps?filename=John%20E%20Grayson%20Ph.D.%20-%20Python%20and%20Tkinter%20Programming-Manning%20Publications%20%282000%29.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding an alternative answer by myself:

I could just use `pydoc` to have the complete module reference.

Comment: The pydoc of Tkinter is not a complete reference. For example; in Python 3.5.2, \_\_init\_\_.py in tkinter module has two match of `validatecommand` string but there is no explanation around there about what it is or how it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Some links no longer function - lately I've been relying on [effbot](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-classes.htm) for all my tkinter documentation needs.