# Where can I find tkinter documentation?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When I look at [the tkinter page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) for Python, it does not have any clear descriptions of what parameters functions take and what functionality can be expected for a particular function.

For example, I am looking for information about the tkinter Canvas function/class (I don't even know what it is...), but the word "canvas" is not mentioned anywhere on the page.

Where can I find the documentation for Tkinter?

EDIT:
It looks like [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_canvas.htm) might have some good documentation, but it's not official. Where can I find the official documentation for Tkinter?

Comment: Asking for links to documentation is off topic for stackoverflow

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you for letting me know. Do you know of any good sites where I can ask for links to documentation? It's hard when I'm supposed to do research in order to ask a question about very basic functionality here, but I can't even find the starting place for research.

Comment: I would recommend going to google. Search for `tkinter documentation` and you will get thousands of links.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you, I did try that, but none of them seemed to be official. I had checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755174/where-can-i-find-api-documentation-for-tkinter) but hadn't looked closely enough at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756306/5049813) which contained my solution.

Comment: You already seem to know where the official documentation is, since you link to it in your first sentence. The very top of that documentation provides links to many other sources. I'm not sure what else you are expecting. That documentation provides links to the canonical tk documentation, and provides a guide for how to mentally convert the tcl/tk documentation into python.

Comment: Oh wow, my eyes completely glazed over the yellow box at the top of that documentation. Thank you for pointing that out! I'm sorry for taking up your time with this question that would have been easily answered if I'd just spent a few more minutes looking at what I had already found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Tkinter is just a wrapper over something called Tcl/Tk. The documentation for Tcl/Tk can be found [here](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/). (For example, the [canvas](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm) page.)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter

This is the official documentation from python.org

But there is, as you suggested tutorialspoint.

Also I recommend using: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm